# How to add posts to wp_query result?

Tags: posts, wp-query, query

I have 2 user groups: **authors** and **clients**

Authors can publish posts and specify in metabox for wich **client** these post is ment for.

Client can publish posts and view, edit posts, created by **Authors** for them.

**Problem:**

In wp-admin on posts screen ( *wp-admin/edit.php* ) i need to display:

if **Author**: only author posts

if **Client**: client posts and posts **where meta value is client id**

if **admins**: all posts

I'v added `pre_get_posts` filter to filter only author posts:

```
/**
 * Show only author posts, but all for admins
**/
function m7_24_ee_posts_for_current_author( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_admin && 'post' == $query->query_vars['post_type'] && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        global $user_ID;
        $query->set( 'author',  $user_ID );
        if( current_user_can( 'client' ) ) {
            $query->set( 'meta_key', 'client' );
            $query->set( 'meta_value', $user_ID );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'm7_24_ee_posts_for_current_author' );
```

But the problem is that `meta_key` and `author` fields acts like `AND`, but i need them to be 'OR`. **or author is $user_ID or meta_value is $user_ID**

If there's no easy solution for these than it can be made by marging 2 queryies ( 1 with author and 2 with meta value ), but the problem is that i don't know which hook should i use to marge them, becouse `pre_get_posts` is fiering to early.

Comment: may be, but since i'm working in dashboard ( wp-admin/edit.php ) screen, there's less chance of writing custom code. And if you understand my question i was asking where ( how ) ( wich hook to use ) to write these code, becouse pre_get_posts doesn't fits..

Comment: Please (1) format your question properly (WYSIWYG editor) and (2) show us what you have tried and there you failed. By now it's just a task and nothing that can be worked on.

Comment: updated, added code samples, hope it helps to understand my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hack for the main *post* query in `wp-admin` that should do the trick:

```
/**
 * Modification of the wp-admin main (post) query: 
 *     If current user has the "client" role then 
 *     show client's posts OR posts where the "client" meta value is the client id.
 *
 * @see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173967/26350
 */

function wpse_pre_get_posts( $q )
{
    if( is_admin()
        && $q->is_main_query()
        && 'post' === $q->get( 'post_type' ) 
        && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' )  
    ) 
    {
        $q->set( 'author',  get_current_user_id() );
        if( current_user_can( 'client' ) ) 
        {
            $q->set( 'author',  null );
            $q->set( 'meta_key', 'client' );
            $q->set( 'meta_value', get_current_user_id() );
            add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_posts_where' );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_pre_get_posts' );
```

where the callback for the `posts_where` filter is defined as:

```
function wpse_posts_where( $where )
{
    global $wpdb;
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    return str_ireplace(
        "{$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key",
        sprintf( 
            "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author = %d 
             OR {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key", 
            get_current_user_id() 
        ),
        $where
    );
}
```

where I assume there are **no** other meta queries on the main *post* query in `wp-admin`. If that's not the case, then you should be able to refine this further.

Comment: Totaly forgot we can query database :(( should figure it by my self. Thanks a lot, worked)