# How to restrict subscriber editing other posts but read specific posts in backend

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I need to allow Subscribers to edit their posts (done) and read (see in backend) posts of specific author or with specific ID (to make copies of it). I found the code, but that's not enough:

```
function posts_for_current_author ($query) {
        if( $query->is_admin && 'edit.php' == $GLOBALS['pagenow'] && !current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' ) ) {
            $query->set('author', $GLOBALS['user_ID'] );
        }
        return $query;
    };
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query posts with more than one author ID, you can use `author__in` parameter. This makes posts from chosen authors visible (read only) for the current user.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'posts_for_current_author');
function posts_for_current_author($query) {
    if (
        $query->is_admin &&
        'edit.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] &&
        ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' )
    ) {
        $query->set('author__in', array(get_current_user_id(), 1, 2, 3) ); // add 1 or more user IDs
    }
    return $query;
};
```

One option query posts with multiple author IDs and post IDs is to manipulate the `where` clause with `posts_where` filter. I picked idea for this from an [old WPSE Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173928/how-to-add-posts-to-wp-query-result). This makes posts from chosen authors and chosen posts visible (read only) to the current user.

With this you can do `OR` comparison instead of `AND`, which using both `author__in` and `post__in` in `pre_get_posts` would cause. *(At least based on the test I ran locally)*

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'wpse_posts_where' );
function wpse_posts_where( $where ) {
    if (
        is_admin() &&
        'edit.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] &&
        ! current_user_can( 'edit_others_posts' )
    ) {
        remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
        global $wpdb;

        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $authors = array(
            $current_user_id,
            1,
            2,
            3,
        );

        $posts = array(
            1,
            2,
            3,
        );

        return str_ireplace(
            "{$wpdb->posts}.post_author in ({$current_user_id})",
            sprintf(
                "({$wpdb->posts}.post_author in (%s) OR {$wpdb->posts}.ID in (%s))",
                implode(',', $authors),
                implode(',', $posts)
            ),
            $where
        );
    } else {
        return $where;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you! I guess with pages is the same, just change post to pages?

Comment: @JulianaJul Yes, I think that just changing the post IDs to page IDs should be enough.